# find the visible height of my iframed page - (fb page)

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, height, colorbox

My page is displayed in an iframe (facebook page)  It is around 2000px tall, but of course only a few hundered are visble at any time.

Is it possible to find out the visible hieght of my page? Using $window.width() is giving me the total height of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facebook javascript sdk has the method *[FB.Canvas.getPageInfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/)*:

> As a Canvas app runs within an iframe it does not have access to
>   window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth. This method exists to
>   provide access to the client (browser) dimensions as well as the
>   current scroll position and offset coordinates.

It's easy to use:

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
    function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    }
);
```

From that info you should be able to calculate what you need.

Comment: Well, i dont have the rep to vote this up, but this is helpful, thanks.  The scroll_top is giving me what i need, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: Well, if this answers your question then you can accept the answer (clicking the "v" icon below the voting)